# Possible to maintain php HipHop code?

Tags: php, hiphop

I've been reading a lot about Facebook's PHP HipHop project, but one thing I can't seem to figure out (I don't have a 64 bit machine to test HipHop on) is whether or not one could use HipHop as simply a project conversion tool, rather than just to compile a binary.

Essentially if one were so inclined to try to convert a PHP CLI application to C++ using HipHop, would it therefore be possible to just maintain it in C++ in the future, rather than having to use HipHop every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect that automatically translated code will be harder to maintain than handwritten code. It will be generated by a computer so you can get rid of things like loops in many places. A lot of things might be sub optimal (direct translation cannot always accommodate for idioms) and after hand tweaking this for a while, it will be a mix of styles (auto generated and hand written) which will be a maintenance nightmare.

Essentially, you should treat this C++ code just like a binary after a regular compilation. Would you bit tweak that to add new functionality? No, you'd edit the source and then recompile it. That's what you should do here as well. The C++ is *generated* and an intermediate representation. The fact that it's in a human readable language shouldn't tempt you to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

The source C++ generated by HipHop is perfectly capable of being modified. People do use HipHop for this. It would not make sense to expand greatly on HipHop generated C++ since it is not so easy to follow as hand-written code (or anywhere near as efficient), but for small changes (perhaps optimizing) it can be done.

Also HipHop can be used to generated a base which you can then completely rewrite if you wanted to convert a PHP script to C++. You can start by looking at the HipHop generated code to help you rewrite the entire thing by hand.